# Messed up with sysctl settings on Precise. Is there a way to restore defaults?

Tags: 12.04, networking, performance

In a quest to improvise internet speed on my slow broadband, I messed up with the below tcp settings in sysctl.conf after following instructions from [here](http://tuxradar.com/content/make-linux-faster-and-lighter). I edited the sysctl.conf, performed "sysctl -p" and also performed a full restart! Unfortunately I did not take any backup of the file or default settings. Now, my internet speed is even slower than what it was. Is there a way now to set all these kernel settings to their defaults without performing a total re-installation of ubuntu? (Commenting them in sysctl.conf is not helping)

Here are the settings:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0
net.core.rmem_max = 8388608
net.core.wmem_max = 8388608
net.core.rmem_default = 16384
net.core.wmem_default = 16384
#4096   16384   905792
#4096   16384   64240
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 16384 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 8192 87380 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 4096 16384 8388608
#net.ipv4.route.flush=1
```

Comment: Just comment out them and reboot. Check the new values with sysctl command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/etc/sysctl.conf comes from the "procps" package:

> steven@wind:~$ dpkg -S /etc/sysctl.conf
>   procps: /etc/sysctl.conf

If you move your bad copy and re-install procps with the "--force-confmiss" dpkg option, it will restore the original sysctl.conf file.

```
sudo mv /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.conf.bad 
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall procps
```

Then reboot.

On every boot, the kernel loads with the default parameters. Later, the values in sysctl.conf are applied. If you reboot with the default sysctl.conf in place, you should have all the same values as a clean install (assuming no other hacks being applied in other init scripts).

Once you're back to normal, do yourself a favor and:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core etckeeper
```

It's a version tracking system for all your config files in /etc. It'll let you view the history for all your config files, see what changed when, and roll them back as needed.

http://evilrouters.net/2011/02/18/using-etckeeper-with-git-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Staven, unfortunately reverting to default sysctl.conf won't help. The default settings for 
net.ipv4.tcp_mem and net.core.rmem_default are not stored in sysctl.conf, but the kernel sets it automatically. But now those auto settings are lost since they are over-ridden with my sysctl settings. Do you know how to get the kernel set it automatically once again ?

Comment: I should have mentioned - the changes you make outside of sysctl.conf won't be persistent across reboots. The kernel loads the default parameters each time you boot, and then overrides those with the values in sysctl.conf. If you reboot with the standard sysctl.conf, you get the standard kernel parameters (assuming no other hacks or scripts are adjusting them).